# Is there an alternative library to Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel?

Tags: c#, excel

I am using the `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel` reference in order to have some manipulations with excel files, like adding columns, locking cells, protecting with password etc...

Now I have to use this code on a server that doesn't have office installed on it, so I don't really know for sure if the code using this reference will be able to run there.
So is there a way of doing all these actions on excel files on a server that doesn't have office installed on it ?
Should I use another library or is there a way that the `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel` reference to work with no office installed ?

Comment: Why are you using code that manipulates Excel, on a server that doesn't have Office installed?

Comment: There are libraries that can do Excel file manipulation without having to install Excel itself. Library advice is offtopic for SO, so search the web a bit. :) Using those libraries you'll have to rewrite some of your code though.

Comment: http://www.aspose.com/.net/total-component.aspx

Comment: A word of warning: Any available "Office compatible" library will do just a subset of what office does. Only MS Office is fully compatible.

Comment: I found this: [VSTO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_Studio_Tools_for_Office). Does anyone  know this library ?

Comment: I use EPPlus to manipulate Excel on the server (http://epplus.codeplex.com/). Easy install via NuGet in Visual Studio.

Comment: VSTO won't help you - if a high-level library on top of the COM object model, for making Office add-ins (so would require Excel to be present too).

Comment: Yes, I thought so too... Thanks for the heads up :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[ClosedXML](https://github.com/closedxml/closedxml) is another open source library for manipulating Excel files (with an API similar to the COM object model).

Answer (score 6):

You can use EPPlus. It works with Open Office Xml format. No need to install any Office component on the server.
https://github.com/EPPlusSoftware/EPPlus

Answer (score 1):

Another open-source option is [spreadsheetlight](http://spreadsheetlight.com/). I have been using it for quite some time now.

Answer (score 1):

[EasyXLS](http://www.easyxls.com) is also a library for Excel file manipulation that covers all the requests that you mentioned.